# interpreting the sentence structure of わたしが五歳のころ，近所の叔母さんの家が, 小さなエビを見せてくれた as it reads to me as an inanimate object taking an action

Tags: grammar, meaning

The book i'm reading starts with the sentence 'わたしが五歳のころ，近所の叔母さんの家が, 小さなエビを見せてくれた' which when i translate gives me something like 'When I was five years old, my neighbor's aunt's house showed me a small shrimp' i have no idea what that means and am struggling to understand the grammer in a way that allows me to infer meaning from the sentence

Comment: Should be a typo for 近所の**家のおばさん**が. https://scontent-itm1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/214109910_4124324891008696_3912142296067125613_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=Dj3CRVP5ipwAX_1YYaT&_nc_ht=scontent-itm1-1.xx&oh=0541c7916597d0776fceb368411b6a4d&oe=60EF8F81